Cannot find Ubuntu Studio menu after running Ubuntu Studio Installer
I received a new System76 desktop preloaded with Ubuntu 24.04. I updated the package versions, then ran Ubuntu Studio Installer. I included the Ubuntu Studio menu in the Ubuntu Studio Installer checklist, though I cannot find it after the installer completed (though the rest of the Ubuntu Studio apps appear to be loaded). Have restarted multiple times.
Do I need to install Plasma? Or is there some other step necessary to use the Ubuntu Studio menu?
Here's what I have now for a menu, one out of 7 pages of menu;


I've used Ubuntu Studio for at least a decade, and love the hierarchical menu. I had plain vanilla Ubuntu 24.04 loaded on my new System76 desktop, so I ran Ubuntu Studio Installer, after which no changes ocurred to the menu (except that the 'flat' menu system now is 7 pages worth of icons. How to I enable the Ubuntu Studio hierarchical menu?

ubuntustudio-menu is not an application. Installing this package added a lot of .desktop-files to /usr/share/applications/. You should now have menu categories like Photography, Mixers, Effects and so on. here a list of files this package will install in noble.

Please take a look here, looks like it's what you're looking for. The package gnome-shell-extensions is available from official repositories. Sorry, I can't give you more details and didn't test it myself, I never used vanilla Ubuntu, always used Ubuntu Studio.

Installing ubuntustudio-menu alone doesn't cut it. There's one more step:

run "Reset Application Overview"

That will organize the Application Overview into folders. That's the closest functionality of Ubuntu Studio's hierarchical menu in the GNOME desktop that Ubuntu Studio can provide.

Excellent tip, @erich-eickmeyer That provided the organization of many applications added by Ubuntu Studio into folders on Gnome Overview. I continued arranging other apps with the procedure laid out at https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-create-folders-in-gnome-44-to-declutter-the-application-overview/
